# PDF Ad tracking

Tags: tracking, pdf

I run a PDF magazine that contains paid advertising and I need to be able to track how many people click on the ads and visit my advertisers' websites. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the links to advertiser sites inside PDFs?

Answer (score 3):

Simply don't make your links `advertiser1.com` but instead use something like `yourdomain.com/ad.php?redir=www.advertiser1.com` then, have a simple ad.php (or whatever) script on your site which will increase view counter for given advertiser and then do a HTTP 301 redirect to site given as `redir` parameter.